# Passing a callback function to jQuery AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm trying to pass in a function to run when the AJAX call is successful, however it's not working as it say's that "callback is not a function".

Example:

Calling Code:

```
getGrades(var);
```

JS:

```
function getGrades(grading_company) {

    // Set file to get results from..
    var loadUrl = "ajax_files/get_grades.php";

    // Set data string
    var dataString = 'gc_id=' + grading_company;

    // Set the callback function to run on success
    var callback = 'showGradesBox';

    // Run the AJAX request
    runAjax(loadUrl, dataString, callback);

}

function showGradesBox(response) {

    // Code here...

}

function runAjax(loadUrl, dataString, callback) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: loadUrl,
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'html',
        error: ajaxError,
        success: function(response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });    

}
```

Now if I replace this line below with the function name itself it works:

```
callback(response);
```

But I can't get it to work like above where I get the function name from a passed in parameter.

Comment: You can't pass a string as a function, but if it's inside an object literal you can use bracket notation, or if it's global, you can use `window[callback]` to reference a variable in the global scope, and assign the function instead of using a function decleration.

Comment: On the other hand, after looking at it, just returning the promise from the ajax function, and using `done()` would be a lot simpler, like so -> [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/udirup/3/edit)

Comment: @adeneo So that will only run on success?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`showGradesBox` is a string in your code. So you have two options to execute the callback function:

If you want to keep the string you can use

```
this[callback](response);
```

(if `callback` is defined in global scope you can also use `window[callback](response);`

Or you can pass the function directly:

```
var callback = showGradesBox;
```

(in this case you can keep your existing code for callback execution)