# How to run one getJSON after another based on the results of the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

In my application, I am trying to gather data from two different sources. So first it has to `loop.each` in to an internal JSON file and see if the data is found, if not, it has to request another `$.getjson()` to get the data from an external source.

So the second `$.getjson()` is dependant on the first one and sometimes does not need to be run if the the data is already found in the first one.

**First `$.getjson()` call:**

```
$.getJSON(InternalURL, function (data) {
     $.each(data.Source, function (index, value) {
           if(artist.indexOf(value.keyword) > -1){
                 image = value.image;
                 $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(" + image + ")");
           }
     });

 });
```

**Second `$.getjson()` call:**

```
$.getJSON(ExternalURL, function (data) {
    image = data.artist.image;
    (".bg").css("background-image", "url(" + image + ")");
});
```

The other consideration is the timing of this process. Of course it has to be done as fast as possible, so the it wont be noticeable in the interface.

**UPDATE**
Example using Async / Await  based on the answer provided by @Tiny Giant
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbpsoxf4/2/)
Currently this code works on JSFiddle, but in the actual application, while it works fine, it gives a Console error as "**Uncaught (in promise)**" with an object of methods such as, `always`, `abort`, `fail`, and etc. Any idea why this error comes up?

Comment: You should use promises.

Comment: Or even `await`.

Comment: Just use a callback function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185402/passing-a-callback-function-to-jquery-ajax-success-function

Comment: @user3739842 Thanks for your comment. The provided link uses ajax callback. even tho ajax and getjson are the same, but I can only use getjson, and as i tested it,  it seems the call back runs before the main body code is completed... However if I am wrong It would be great if you provide a sample code.

Comment: @ideaboxer By await do you mean using `$.when().done()` ?! I tried it, I put first getjson in the `when()` and using an if statement in the `done()` section I controlled it if the second `getjson` is required. But I noticed it runs the `done()` part even before the `when()` is completed. If I did wrongly and you like to see it I can update the code.

Comment: @SLaks I am not sure how to use promises when running there the second `getjson` depends on the results of the first one. It would be if you provide a sample code.

Comment: @DannyBoy Do you need to run the second ajax call when artist.indexOf(value.keyword) > -1 ?

Comment: Where does `artist` come from in your first `getJSON`?

Comment: [This is how I would rewrite your question](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/71d7dd4c9b1b92fef94083cb89dd5291). As it is such a drastic change, I'm leaving this comment instead of performing the edit myself. If you feel it accurately portrays the original intent of your question and is an improvement, please feel free to [edit] the question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Async / Await](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/) (initially defined in the [ECMAScript® 2017 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html)). See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions) for information on current support.

This works by pausing the current execution context and removing it from the stack once the `getJSON` call begins. Once the `$.getJSON` call returns, the paused execution context will be added back onto the stack, then execution will continue once the preceding items in the stack have been processed.

```js
(async () => {
    const post = await $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    const comments = await $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments');
    post.comments = comments.filter(e => e.postId === post.id);
    console.log(post);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To apply this to your specific example, you could use the following code:

```
(async () => {
    let image, data = await $.getJSON(InternalURL);
    if(data) {
        for(let value of data.Source) {
            if(!image && artist.indexOf(value.keyword) > -1) {
                image = value.image;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // request failed
    }
    if(!image) {
        let data = await $.getJSON(ExternalURL);
        if(data) {
            image = data.artist.image;
        } else {
            // request failed
        }
    }
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(" + image + ")");
})();
```

This requests the first resource, then—once that request is completed and execution is continued—it checks the response as your example does. If the script doesn't find what it is looking for in the first response, it initiates the second request. Once execution is continued, it sets the background image.

### Further reading:

- [Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [Await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

---

Another option would be to use callbacks. This method is more difficult to follow, but is supported everywhere.

```js
$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', post => {
    $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments', comments => {
        post.comments = comments.filter(e => e.postId === post.id);
        console.log(post);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. It seems close to what I am looking for but I cannot understand which part checks the value in order to decide whether to do the second getjson. For example if there is initially `var image = "";`, if the first getjson finds the right data it change the `image` value, and if the first getjson is done without change in the value of `image` then it goes for the second getjson request. Could you please edit the code in a way that I can understand this control part? Thanks

Comment: @DannyBoy I've updated my answer to include an example of the concept applied to the specific example provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does the job. however, before I choose it as answer, could you please check the updated section of my post and let me know why the console error comes up? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is missing `.catch();` at the end of it. but I do not know what I have to put inside the `.catch()`.

Comment: Shoot me a link to an example reproducing the error and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON(InternalURL, function (data) {
     $.each(data.Source, function (index, value) {
           if(artist.includes(value.keyword)){
                 if (value.image) {
                     image = value.image;
                     $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(" + image + ")");
                 } else {
                     $.getJSON(ExternalURL, function (data) {
                         image = data.artist.image;
                         (".bg").css("background-image", "url(" + image + ")");
                     });
                 }
           }
     });
 });
```